# Google Tag Manager - click on link with specific text

Tags: google-analytics, seo, google-tag-manager

How can I track click on a link with "specific text"?

In short I want to track link which contains or giving output on my app "specific text"?

Can I track it by value text or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside Variables tab you can add predefined variables such as Click Text. Once you have that, create a Trigger with Click Text equal to the text you want to target and that will be the trigger you use for the tag.